# Connect vector using Parcel

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-5

In OpenLayers v5.3.0 using Parcel does not connect the vector layer from a local location.

This code with local URL does not work:

```
import GeoJSON from 'ol/format/GeoJSON';
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import VectorLayer from 'ol/layer/Vector';
import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector';
import View from 'ol/View';

var map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new VectorLayer({
      source: new VectorSource({
        format: new GeoJSON(),
        url: './data/geojson/countries.geojson'
      })
    })
  ],
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  })
});
```

This code works:

```
import GeoJSON from 'ol/format/GeoJSON';
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import VectorLayer from 'ol/layer/Vector';
import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector';
import View from 'ol/View';

var map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new VectorLayer({
      source: new VectorSource({
        format: new GeoJSON(),
        url: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.0/examples/data/geojson/countries.geojson'
      })
    })
  ],
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  })
});
```

This code works without Parcel:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
   new ol.layer.Vector({
     source: new ol.source.Vector({
     url: './data/geojson/countries.geojson',
     format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
     })
    })
   ],
target: 'map',
view: new ol.View({
center: [0, 0],
zoom: 3
})
```

});

What prevents connecting "countries.geojson" from local location using Parcel?

Comment: See https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/323  If, as in the final comment, it affects images other data files will also be affected.